# Insert RadioButton in a group of an Expandable List View

Tags: android, radio-button, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an Expandable List View with some groups that contain a RadioButton.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgL0F.png)

The problem is that only one of those RadioButton can be enabled at the same time, but now I can select all of them.

Here is the code of the adapter implemented

```
public class ActionPlanExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ActionPlan> listActionPlan;
    private Map<ActionPlan,ArrayList<Contact>> mapChild;

    public ActionPlanExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ActionPlan> listActionPlan, Map<ActionPlan, ArrayList<Contact>> mapChild) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listActionPlan = listActionPlan;
        this.mapChild = mapChild;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String groupTitle = context.getString(R.string.actionPlanGroupHeader) + (groupPosition+1);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.action_plan_alarm_expandable_group, null);
        }
        TextView tvGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlertName);
        tvGroup.setText(groupTitle);

        RadioButton selectGroup = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbSelectActionPlan);
        selectGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Contact contact = getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        String item = contact.getName();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.action_plan_alarm_expandable_child, null);

        TextView contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
        TextView contactRelationship = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactRelationship);
        TextView contactPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactPhoneNumber);

        contactName.setText(contact.getName());
        contactRelationship.setText(contact.getRelationship());
        contactPhoneNumber.setText(Integer.toString(contact.getPhoneNumber1()) + ", " + Integer.toString(contact.getPhoneNumber2()) + ", " + Integer.toString(contact.getPhoneNumber3()));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have only bad adapter implementation

try something like that in

`getGroupView {
...
RadioButton selectGroup =(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbSelectActionPlan);
selectGroup.setChecked(isExpanded);
...
}`

i dont know which attribute set check radio button. 
You must have same attribute in your model when you keep radio btn is check or not. Or when is Expanded set radio btn check.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve the problem. First add this variable to the adapter.

```
private int selectedPosition = -1;
```

And after I modified getGroupView.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String groupTitle = context.getString(R.string.actionPlanGroupHeader) + (groupPosition+1);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.action_plan_alarm_expandable_group, null);
    }
    TextView tvGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlertName);
    tvGroup.setText(groupTitle);

    RadioButton selectGroup = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbSelectActionPlan);
    selectGroup.setChecked(groupPosition == selectedPosition);
    selectGroup.setTag(groupPosition);
    selectGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonCheckChanged(view);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private void buttonCheckChanged(View view) {
    selectedPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: use parameter isExpanded  when is group selected parameter is true you dont need set tags and check positions

Comment: Using isExpanded I associate the expand action to the RadioButton but I still can select more than one option if I press on the RadioButton. Probably my implementation is not the best, but with it I can select the option that I want, regardless of the expanded element and I eliminating the possibility of select more than one RadioButton at a time.